# How can I call a function, when Facebook has been authourized? Not able to call FB.ui

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-login

How can I call a function, when Facebook has been authourized?
I need to pass it to another page based on success. If it's authorised I want to forward it to new jsp. How can I call that function?
I read that through Fb.ui we may write callback function. But how FB.ui will be called? I tried but how to call FB.ui?

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener after FB.init

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID from the App Dashboard
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File for x-domain communication
      status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
      cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
    });

  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
      alert('The status of the session is: ' + response.status);
      window.location.replace('http://www.NEW_URL.COM/');
  });
});
```

The response object passed in will contain:

```
{
  status: "",         /* Current status of the session */
  authResponse: {          /* Information about the current session */
    userID: ""          /* String representing the current user's ID */
    signedRequest: "",  /* String with the current signedRequest */
    expiresIn: "",      /* UNIX time when the session expires */
    accessToken: "",    /* Access token of the user */
  }
}
```

Depending on your requirement, you may listen to other auth related events - see the facebook developer docs for subscribing to events here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/